# how to convert Taxonomy terms to nodes

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, migrations

**Short Question :**

- is there a way convert all of one vocabulary taxonomy terms to one
  content type nodes ? And switch all term refrences in the database to
  entity references to the converted term/nodes?

**Details :**

- A long time ago, I have made a website for music and i used the core
  terms for local singers and performers now i want to use entity
  reference for a better content control user interface.

  the website has one **content type** "Audio File" The content type
  fields are :

  - **Audio file** : file upload
  - **Performer** : term reference of vocab "Performers"

  The taxonomy term fields are -Vocab : "**Performers**:

  - **Performer Name** : title field.
  - **Performer Portrait** : Image upload field

the site is running and there is already more than 150 singers and over 1000 audio files. So doing this manually is almost impossible.
I think i should use migrate module but i don't know how to use it and it seems very complicated !

Thanks :)

Comment: Your use case is uncommon, you will need to code it yourself I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Export taxonomy using https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv

Then use excelent https://drupal.org/project/feeds module and create node importer and map fields accoridingly.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is not a "ready-to-use" waay to do this.

You could create a custom module. Supposing that you have already created and configured:

- the new content type "performers" with all fields (with a field called "old id" there will have the "old" tid from the term
- the "audio" content type with entity  reference to Performers

you could create a module that:

- get all terms from the vocabulary
- for every term you create a node "performer", with values from terms and using the tid for the field "old id"

After this you could:

- get all nodes of type "audio"
- for every node you get the "tid" value of the performer and with views or entity_query_field search for the "performer" node that has "old id" = "tid"
- assign the nid of the performer to the entity reference in "audio"
- save the "audio" node

These could be the "logical" process of the module.